# modified version of selection sort in C

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

I'm trying to modify selection sort in such a way that it puts the biggest element at the end of the array and then repeats selection sort for n - 1 items until n is 0. My code compiles but the output is still an unsorted array, please help me out!

```
#include <stdio.h>
void selection_sort(int arr[], int n);
int main ()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int arr[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  selection_sort(arr, n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  return 0;
}
void selection_sort(int arr[], int n)
{
  if(n <= 0)
  return;
  while(n > 0)
  {
  int max = 0;
  int temp, x;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i] >= max)
    max = arr[i];
    x = i;
  }
  temp = arr[n - 1];
  arr[n - 1] = max;
  arr[x] = temp;
    selection_sort(arr, --n);
  }

}
```

Comment: Use an automatic tool to indent your code, then inspect for obvious mistakes.

Comment: Have you tried debugging a small failing example yet? What were your findings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part

```
    if(arr[i] >= max)
    max = arr[i];
    x = i;
```

is wrong. You forgot to write `{}`, so `x = i;` is executed unconditionally and the swapping after the loop will always be done with the last element. This means that the swapping is done between the same element and it is effectively doing nothing.

Also note that doing both of loop `while(n > 0)` and recursion `selection_sort(arr, --n);` is wasteful. You will need only one of that.

Another note is initializing `max` with `0` will make it behave wrongly when all elements of the input array are negative.

Finally, you should format your code properly with consistent indentation.

Try this:

```
void selection_sort(int arr[], int n)
{
  if(n <= 0)
  return;
  while(n > 0)
  {
    int max = arr[0];
    int temp, x;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if(arr[i] >= max)
      {
        max = arr[i];
        x = i;
      }
    }
    temp = arr[n - 1];
    arr[n - 1] = max;
    arr[x] = temp;
    --n;
  }

}
```

Comment: I just got started with c so I make some really stupid mistakes at times, thank you so much for helping me out!!